# How do I make slides to slide by themself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this problem. I have a page that has slides which doesn't slide by them self and i want that they'd slide. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/tUUPN/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slideshow-nav").css("visibility", "visible");
$("#slideshow-nav a[href=#farm1]").addClass("active");

$("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
    target: '#slideshow',
    axis: 'x'
});

$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function () {
    $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

});
```

EDIT

I updated jsfidde http://jsfiddle.net/tUUPN/10/  (included jquery files at External Resources tab on the left)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be failing for a variety of reasons, at least two being that you didn't include jQuery or your localScroll plugin.

Comment: included both jquery.localscroll.js and jquery.scrollTo.js. When i created this, the example didn't have auto-slide function included. I want to add it to my code, but the problem is I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [jQuery's Animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to produce a sliding effect.  You can read up on the API and examples on that same page.

You can still apply your click functions and such, but you really need animate as a weapon of choice when moving / sliding objects.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to go to the next slide then call that method in setInterval. The number of milliseconds determines how often it fires. Use clearInterval if u want it to stop.